# Issue in accessing tomcat via ipaddress instead of localhost

Tags: tomcat, webserver

My problem is strange..

I deployed my project in apache, and if accessed via local host(http://localhost:8080/MyProject), everything is rendered fine. If accessed through ip address (i.e., 172.x.x.x:8080/MyProject).. page is loading but I can see distortions on page and some widgets missing.. There is large data(around 1MB) coming from server each time(I dont suspect that as problem because there is no error with parsing of json)..

If fire wall issue, then it should not be accessible at all, but it is accessible however there is some problem I stated.

What could be error? any idea.. pls

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something is wrong with the way you reference your CSS files in the HTML. Try doing a browser "view source" on the distorted page, and see if references to CSS files use the proper path with the IP address.